# what is "am_pss" in android event_log

Tags: android

what is the below log means for?

```
01-01 00:51:58.596157   994  1077 I am_pss  : [994,1000,system,96750592,90464256]
```

I'd appreciate who can help clarify this. highly thanks for your help.

Comment: how you get this log, can you able to give some explanation

Comment: @Sree MTK android platform

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
am_pss (Pid|1|5),(UID|1|5),(Process Name|3),(Pss|2|2),(Uss|2|2)
Both pss and uss in bytes if "2" means bytes
```

Please Refer this

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/donut-release/logcat/event-log-tags
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/EventLogTags.logtags

According to Google's [EventLogTags](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/EventLogTags.logtags), am_pss is "Report collection of memory used by a process". So: garbage collection was triggered.

Comment: this hyperlink is unavaialbe